# No traits for tokio's UdpSocket but yes for tokio's TcpStream?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Tokio's [TcpStream](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.1/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html) has the

`pub fn into_split(self) -> (OwnedReadHalf, OwnedWriteHalf)`

method which returns this tuple where each element implements `AsyncWrite` and `AsyncRead`. This way I can create an HTTP client that accepts things that implement `AsyncWrite` and `AsyncRead`.

I couldn't find any similar concept for [UdpSocket](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.13/tokio/net/udp/struct.UdpSocket.html). So, if I'm writing a library that uses tokio's `UdpSocket` then I cannot accept other implementations for `UdpSocket` because it's not a trait.

Is there something I'm missing? I'd like my client to use `UdpSocket` but also users could provide their own implementations of an async `UdpSocket`

Answer (score 0):

[UdpFramed](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.6.7/tokio_util/udp/struct.UdpFramed.html) is what you want, from the `tokio_util` crate.

> A unified Stream and Sink interface to an underlying UdpSocket, using
> the Encoder and Decoder traits to encode and decode frames.

More pertinent to you:

> If you want to work more directly with the streams and sink, consider
> calling [split](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.split) on the UdpFramed returned by this method, which will
> break them into separate objects, allowing them to interact more
> easily.

It looks like the `Sink` half inherits `AsyncWrite` for free (per [tokio docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/io/trait.AsyncWrite.html)), but turning the `Stream` half into `AsyncRead` requires using this other `tokio-util` struct: [StreamReader](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.6.7/tokio_util/io/struct.StreamReader.html)

> Convert a Stream of byte chunks into an AsyncRead.